# Media queries to reposition images

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm using media queries to turn my website more responsive but I'm not sure how to do that with images.
I've used `position: absolute` otherwise when the screen became really narrow the images would "get out" of the screen width and disappear to the left. So I would like some way that they could stay in the centre but either with a smaller size or in a column display which I can't figure it out how to do without them staying on top of each other. Can someone help me with this?

As you won't have the images to see the actual effect this is how it looks with a screen with a  wide width :

[image]

This is how it looks with the properties that I used to centre them in a narrow screen:

[image]

and even more narrow

[image]

This is the code I used:

```css
    @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .header-container.row,
  .section-1.row,
  .section-2.row,
  .section-3.row,
  .section-5.row,
  .section-6.row,
  .section-7.row {
    flex-direction: column;
    .work-images {
      position: relative;
    }
    .first-line.row,
    .second-line.row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: absolute;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .pcontainer {
      width: 350px;
    }
    .first-line img,
    .second-line img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 250px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row work-images">
  <div class="row first-line">
    <div class="pcontainer">
      <img src="magazine.jpg" width="333.33" height="250" class="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="pcontainer">
      <img src="Magazine3.jpg" width="333.33" height="250" class="image" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row second-line">
    <div class="pcontainer">
      <img src="poster.png" max-width="450" height="250" class="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="pcontainer">
      <img src="poster2.png" max-width="450" height="250" class="image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should remove the absolute positioning altogether.

Comment: Without that the images would completely disappear from the screen ...

Comment: absolute positioning shouldn't be used for this, either flexbox or grid.

Comment: What other option do I have then to get the effect that I want?

Comment: If you want to stick to absolute positioning, I think your only option (without involving ugly js or css eval) is to set a fixed height for the images and position everything manually.